# Is a limit point compact subset of a Hausdorff space necessarily closed?

Tags: general-topology

This is Exercise 3 c) from Section 28 of Munkres - Topology.  I had thought the answer was no initially, but the example I came up with was not Hausdorff.  At this point, I'm just not sure.  Here's what I've done so far:

Suppose $X$ is not closed. Then $X$ has a limit point $x\in Z\setminus X$.  Let $U_0$ be neighborhood of $x$, then there is an $x_1\in U_0\cap X$.  Because, $Z$ is Hausdorff, $U_0$ is Hausdorff.  So, we can recursively define for each $n$, distinct $x_n\in U_{n-1}$ and disjoint neighborhoods $V_n,U_n\subseteq U_{n-1}$ of $x_n,z$ respectively.  Because, $V_n\subseteq U_{n-1}\setminus U_n$, $V_n\cap V_m=\emptyset$ whenever $n\ne m$.  Therefore, each $x_n$ is an isolated point.

My problem now is that I can't claim that $x$ is a limit point of $\{x_n\}$. I may well not be if $Z$ is not first countable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And in fact the first counterexample that comes to mind works precisely because the point $x_0$ is not a point of first countability. I don’t remember whether Munkres uses the standard name $\omega_1$ or calls it $\Omega$, but you want the space $Z$ to be the linearly ordered space of ordinals less than or equal to the first uncountable ordinal, $[0,\omega_1]$ or $[0,\Omega]$, depending on your notation. $Z$ is even a compact Hausdorff space. Let $X=[0,\omega_1)$ (or $[0,\Omega)$); it’s a standard example of a limit point space that is not compact, and it’s clearly not closed in $Z$.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  I did think about this example briefly.  For some reason, I thought $X$ would not be limit point compact, but I see my mistake now.

Comment: @Tim: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you explain this answer a little bit?

Comment: @JohnMars: If $A$ is an infinite subset of $X$, it must contain a strictly increasing sequence $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of countable ordinals. This set, being countable, is bounded in $X$ and has a supremem $\alpha$, and the nature of the order topology ensures that in fact the sequence converges to $\alpha$. Thus, $\alpha$ is a limit point of the set $A$.